# Difference between length and number (in the draftwatermark package)

Tags: packages, lengths, draftwatermark

I am using the `draftwatermark` package. According to the [documentation](http://ctan.mirrorcatalogs.com/macros/latex/contrib/draftwatermark/draftwatermark.pdf), it is possible to set the horizental position of a watermark with the command `\SetWatermarkHorCenter{⟨length⟩}`. They say that `<length>` is a length and not a simple number. What does this mean? How can I enter a length equal to f.ex. 1cm or 10% of the page height?

Comment: A length is either a number with a length unit (pt or cm etc.) or specified as length register, which has then to be set to a length value (again, with unit). With the package `calc` you could say `0.1\paperheight` however, since `\paperheight` is a length register (predefined, already)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer `0.1\paperheight` is legal in standard TeX.

Comment: @egreg: Yes, I confused with it with addition of lengths (using `calc` and not `\dimexpr` then)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I updated the draftwatermark package to 1.2 and it works fine (PDFLaTeX) with the following setting.

```
\usepackage{draftwatermark}
\SetWatermarkText{\textsc{Confidential}}
\SetWatermarkScale{0.7}
\SetWatermarkAngle{0}
\SetWatermarkColor{red}
\SetWatermarkHorCenter{0.5\paperwidth}
\SetWatermarkVerCenter{0.5\paperheight}
```

Hope this helps?